# DataBinding.ObservableArrayList not updating when data added via RoomDatabase.Callback() onCreate() on first app open

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-room

I've been reading [this article](https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1) from a Google Developer Advocate on best practices with Room. It mentions using the `RoomDatabase.Callback()` to add data to the database when it's first created.

This all works fine but when the `Activity` loads the data hasn't been added. Once the data has been added, my data binding doesn't update with the new data. However, on reopening the app, it will have the data. Is this some race condition that I'm running into? I'm using Dagger2 which isn't included in the example code.

```
@Volatile private var andiDatabase: AndiDatabase? = null

private fun getInstance(): AndiDatabase =
    andiDatabase ?: synchronized(this) {
        andiDatabase ?: buildDatabase().also { andiDatabase = it }
    }

private fun buildDatabase(): AndiDatabase {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(application.applicationContext, AndiDatabase::class.java,
        "andi-database")
        .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)
                ioThread {
                    getInstance().andiDAO().insert(*databasePopulator.getAndisList())
                }
            }
        })
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideAndiDatabase(): AndiDatabase {
    return buildDatabase()
}
```

My `ViewModel`:

```
val andis: LiveData<List<Andi>> = andiDao.getAllAndis()
val andisList: ObservableArrayList<Andi> = ObservableArrayList()
```

The observing is done in my `Activity`'s `onCreate()`:

```
private fun observeDatabase() {
    viewModel.andis
        .observe(this, Observer {
            it?.let {
                viewModel.andisList.clear()
                viewModel.andisList.addAll(it)
            }
        })
}
```

On debugging this, only the empty value is observed.